# Custom menu Separator templated via Generic.xaml

Tags: wpf, menu, separator

I develop a DLL library that extends WPF `Menu`/`MenuItem` classes with some features including skinning. This library has the following classes:

```
public class MyMenu : Menu {...}
public class MyMenuItem : MenuItem {...}
```

Each class has a static constructor to override `DefaultStyleKey` so `MyMenu` and `MyMenuItem` use default styles defined in Generic.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyMenu}">...
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyMenuItem}">...
```

Everything works fine. But I also need to realize a custom menu `Separator` which should be templated via Generic.xaml. So I have another class:

```
public class MySeparator : Separator {...}
```

I tried to use the approach described in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.separatorstylekey(VS.85).aspx
This way (Generic.xaml):

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Static local:MyMenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey}" TargetType="{x:Type local:MySeparator}">
 <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
 <Setter Property="Template">
   <Setter.Value>
     <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MySeparator}">
     ...
     </ControlTemplate>
   </Setter.Value>
 <Setter/>
</Style>
```

But it does not work. In my target application I use the DLL library classes as follows 
(MainWindow.xaml):

```
<lib:MyMenu>
  <lib:MyMenuItem Header="Item 1"/>
  <lib:MySeparator/>
  <lib:MyMenuItem Header="Item 2"/>
</lib:MyMenu>
```

So my question is: how to realize a derived menu `Separator` stylized via Generic.xaml?

Comment: Why in the world do you need a derivative class of `Separator`?

Comment: I would like to stylize MySeparator independently from base Separator in simple way: <lib:MySeparator/>. I don't want to specify Style directly for each Separator: <Separator Style="..."/>

Comment: You can implicitly style *all* Seperators just as well, there is no need for this sub-class, just use a normal separator and add a style for that.

Comment: The matter is that i don't want style ALL separators. I want style just particular type which used in MyMenu )

Comment: You could embedd the style for the separator in the style of your menu using the `Style.Resources`.

Comment: I think it's quite suitable solution. Big thanks! Unfortunately my knowledge of WPF is poor... Sorry for 'dummy' question.

Comment: If that works for you, great. Posted it as a proper answer so you could accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not need a new subclass of `Separator`, and you can alternatively style the `Separators` that appear in your menu by embedding a `Style` in the menu's `Style`'s `Resources`.